# How to save XLS file using JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, apache-poi, jfilechooser, xlsxwriter

I have method which is responsible to create an XLS file using Apache POI workbook and I want to save that file using `JFileChooser`. Right now I can able to create that file using file writer and save it to a pre-defined location.

But the requirement is to save that file using `JFileChooser`, and I am not able to understand how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
public void excelFileCreation() 
{
    try
    {
        String path = "D:/";

        String fileName = "EwayBill.xls";

        String filename = path.concat(fileName);

        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Eway Bill");

        Row row1 = sheet.createRow((short)0);
        Row row2 = sheet.createRow((short)0);

        CellRangeAddress transactionDetails = new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 5);
        sheet.addMergedRegion(transactionDetails);
        row2.createCell(0).setCellValue("Transaction details");


        CellRangeAddress fromConsignorDetails = new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 6, 13);
        sheet.addMergedRegion(fromConsignorDetails);
        row2.createCell(6).setCellValue("Transaction details");

        Row rowhead = sheet.createRow((short)1);
        rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("User GSTIN");
        rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("Supply Type");
        rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue("Sub Type");
        rowhead.createCell(3).setCellValue("Document Type");
        rowhead.createCell(4).setCellValue("Document No");

        Row row = sheet.createRow((short)2);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(" ");
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(" ");
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue(" ");
        row.createCell(3).setCellValue(" ");
        row.createCell(4).setCellValue(" ");

        for(int i=0; i<=79; i++)
        {
            sheet.setColumnWidth(i, 6000);
        }

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        wb.write(fileOut);

        fileOut.close();

        if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
        {
          java.io.File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
          // save to file
        }

        System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: [`HSSFWorkbook#write`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#write-java.io.File-) - Documentation should always be your first step, Google/SO should be your second, then posting question when else fails ;)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I followed these steps but still my problem is not solved. That's why i post my problem here.

Comment: `wb.write(file)` ...? Otherwise you're not been clear on your problem

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is most likely to change this:

```
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    wb.write(fileOut);

    fileOut.close();

    if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
    {
      java.io.File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
      // save to file
    }
```

To this:

```
    if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
    {
      java.io.File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
      FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
      wb.write(fileOut);

      fileOut.close();
    }
```

I say 'most likely' because I cannot be sure short of seeing an MCVE / SSCCE.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Thompson.

Comment: Can I post the exact ans here so it will help people?

Comment: Answer is added into your answer please look into it.

Answer (score 1):

The Exact working Solution for the Question is --->

```
if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
 {
    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

    if (file == null) 
     {
       return;
     }

    // It will assign name to the file with extension .xls
     file = new File(file.getParentFile(), file.getName() + ".xls");  

     FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
     wb.write(fileOut);
     fileOut.close();

 }
```

Thanks Andrew Thompson for guidance.